# Same piece of code works on one page & doesnt work on other Page, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

nesting of image inside a `LinkButton` shows image on one page & doesn't show image on another page below are two sample code from two different pages in the same root director.It works fine on one page but on the other page is doesn't show any download image rather shows the text download in place of image.

I have done troubleshooting for sometime and replace the code also but it doesnt show download image for any reason on the second page..

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDownload" runat="server"  onclick="lnkbtnDownload_Click" meta:resourcekey="lnkbtnDownloadResource1">
<asp:Image ID="imgDownload" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png" meta:resourcekey="imgDownloadResource1"  />
</asp:LinkButton>



<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDownload" runat="server"  onclick="lnkbtnDownload_Click" meta:resourcekey="lnkbtnDownloadResource1">
<asp:Image ID="imgDownload" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png" meta:resourcekey="imgDownloadResource1"  />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

HTML OUTPUT

HTML for above two code sample render as below

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lnkbtnDownload','')" id="MainContent_lnkbtnDownload"><img alt="Download" src="images/download.png" id="MainContent_imgDownload"></a>


<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lnkbtnDownload','')" id="MainContent_lnkbtnDownload">Download</a>
```

Both Pages are in the same root directory...

Comment: Issue was resolved by removing `meta:resourcekey="lnkbtnDownloadResource1"` . i am still not able to understand why it is was behaving like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from a discrepancy in your resource files or missing a resource file completely for the second page. Obviously you have one for the first, but possibly not for the other which has different naming.

If you are using meta:resourcekey, there are some things you have to considerate.

> Make sure that your local resource files meet the following criteria:
>
> - They are in an App_LocalResources folder.
> - The base name matches the page name.
>
> For example, if you are working with the page named Default.aspx, the
>   resource files are named Default.aspx.resx (for the default
>   resources), Default.aspx.es.resx, Default.aspx.es-mx.resx, and so on.
>
> The resources in the file use the naming convention
>   resourcekey."property". For example, key name Button1."Text".

**Source**: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093(v=vs.85).aspx)